# Недавно начал изучать c++. Не могу понять почему при выводе даёт 3 числа 14 вместо чисел 12 14 16

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int nums2[3];`
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int o = 12;
        if (o <= 16) {
            o += 2;
            nums2[i] = o;
            cout << nums2[i] << endl;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На первой итерации печатается *12 + 2*. На второй итерации печатается *12 + 2*. И т.д. Вы хотите чтобы на первой итерации `int o = 12;` исполнялся, а на второй нет? Так не бывает. Компилятор делает что вы пишете. А вы пишите "в начале итерации определи пременную `o` и дай ей значение *12*".

Answer (score 0):

Команда

```
        int o = 12;
```

должна быть **перед циклом `for`**, чтобы она определила переменную `o` только один раз:

```
int main() {
    int nums2[3]; 
    int o = 12;                         // здесь
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (o <= 16) {
            o += 2;
            nums2[i] = o;
            cout << nums2[i] << endl;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Затем значение этой переменной в цикле постепенно нарастает, не возвращаясь к оригинальному значению `12`.